# Ionic4 or 3 LoadingController (progress dialog)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using ionic4 LoadingController in the app. it is dismissed after a given interval of time, but don't want like that. I don't want to set the time. before calling web api i will display LoadingController and I want to dismiss it whenever I will get the response from rest service. can anyone help me how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
async function presentLoading() {
      const loader= document.querySelector('ion-loading-controller');
      await loader.componentOnReady();

      const element = await loader.create({
        message: 'Please wait...',
        spinner: 'crescent',
        duration: 2000
      });
      return await element .present();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize variable
private loader: any;
private loaderActive: boolean = false;

// Generic method to display the loader
async showLoader() {
this.loaderActive = true;
this.loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
  message: 'Please wait...',
  spinner: 'crescent',
});
await this.loader.present();
}

// Generic method to dismiss the loader
async dismissLoader() {
if (this.loaderActive === true) {
  await this.loader.dismiss();
}
this.loaderActive = false;
}

Before api call just call the method this.showLoader(), once you get the response 
just call the this.dismissLoader() method.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a guess and say that you are using `HttpClient` to get your data from your rest service, therefore I would propose this scenario for you,
First of all we start by displaying the loader:

```
let loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      //Your loader content and options
    });
loader.present();//show the loader
```

After that we get the data using the `HttpClient`. let suppose that we injected that's way `public http: HttpClient` so it depends on your rest service http mthod (post, get, put ...). the code would be:

```
this.http.get("url").subscribe((data: any) => {
//process your data here
loader.dismiss();//then we hide the loader
});
```

Leave me a comment if I misunderstood it.